# Create Multiple Config files for data

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have data files in the form of pairs.e.g. Sample_27931_RNAX_**R1**.fastq.gz & FASTQ/Sample_27931_RNAX_**R2**.fastq.gz belong to one Sample.Below I have shown the data for 3 samples,each having pairs R1 and R2.

For running the analysis,I create a list of the paths of them separately.So list1 contains all the R1's and list2 contains all the R2's.

Here is the list1 for 3 samples

```
$TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_27931_RNAX_R1.fastq.gz 
$TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_28891_RNAX_R1.fastq.gz 
$TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_28897_RNAX_R1.fastq.gz
```

Here is the list2 for 3 samples

```
$TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_27931_RNAX_R2.fastq.gz
$TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_28891_RNAX_R2.fastq.gz
$TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_28897_RNAX_R2.fastq.gz
```

I want to create configuration files for each Sample(total 3).
The configuration file needs to created separately for each sample.

e.g. A Sample config file is below:

```
**fastq1        = $TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_27931_RNAX_R1.fastq.gz**
**fastq2        = $TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample_27931_RNAX_R2.fastq.gz**

mailto         = r...@gmail.com
thread_no      = 8

detect_integration = yes   # if no is provided, VirusFinder will not detect virus integrations
detect_mutation    = no   # if no is provided, VirusFinder will not detect viral mutations
```

The fastq1 and fastq2 parameters need to be changed using the paths from the list1 and list2 but the rest of the content remains same.How to I create multiple config files using the list1 and list2? the name of config files should be automatically taken from the name of the sample such as Sample_27931_RNAX.config.txt for Sample_27931_RNAX.
Any suggestions or link to any similar posts will be nice.I was not able to find similar posts.

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r samp1; do

b=${samp1%_R1.fastq.gz} samp2=${b}_R2.fastq.gz

cat - <<eof > "${b##*/}.cfg"
**fastq1        = $samp1**
**fastq2        = $samp2**

mailto         = r...@gmail.com
thread_no      = 8

detect_integration = yes  # if no is provided, VirusFinder will not detect virus integrations
detect_mutation    = no   # if no is provided, VirusFinder will not detect viral
eof
done < LIST1
```

Note that List2 is really not necessary, as we are able to graft the name of the second sample fastq from the first itself.